# Dockerized React app - HTTPS=true does not work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, ssl

I have a React app that connects to a backend. The backend is configured for HTTPS and works just fine, until I try to make any requests to it from the React app. I have configured both to be on different subdomains of one common domain (via hosts file; they're both actually running on localhost, although I tried figuring out how to change that) so CORS works fine, but it refuses to set the PHP session cookie because the frontend is HTTP, while the backend is HTTPS:

[image]

Both are running in Docker, separate projects, separate docker-compose files; backend on ports 80/443, frontend on just 3011 (maybe that is the problem, but I can't set frontend to also use ports 80/443 because they're already in use).

I have been trying for way too long to get my Dockerized React app to run in HTTPS mode.
According to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/ (and a ton of other sources on the web, such as https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-setup-https-ssl-in-localhost-react/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neT7fmZ6sDE), it should be as easy as generating a certificate and specifying some environment variables leading to the certificate and its key.

However, when I do that, it still refuses to run in HTTPS mode, and I cannot figure out why that is:
[image: react app running in HTTP mode]

It seems pretty obvious to me that the problem is caused by Docker, but I am not very familiar with it, and I've spent the entire day trying to fix various problems with this whole thing, but this one I just can't handle, so here I am.

`docker-compose.dev.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  node:
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/project
      - /opt/project/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3011:3011"
```

Relevant part of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS dev
WORKDIR /opt/project
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
ENV HTTPS=true
ENV SSL_CRT_FILE=./ssl/cert.pem
ENV SSL_KEY_FILE=./ssl/key.pem
CMD npm run start
```

What causes this cursed React app to not work in HTTPS mode?

Comment: You aren't restricted to port 443 for https, it's just the default

Comment: @Phil great, so it's not the port then. That does not help me at all though. Why the downvote?

Comment: Downvote wasn't me but where I was going with my comment was in regards to where you said _"I can't set frontend to also use ports 80/443 because they're already in use"_

Comment: IMO unless using HTTPS is an absolute necessity (eg using an OAuth2 provider for authentication), I would generally stick to HTTP for general local development. You can use cross-site cookies if both hostnames are the same (eg `localhost`) and you have `SameSite=Lax` in the cookie config

Comment: My backend comes with HTTPS by default (https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker) and stripping it out would be even more work, and my nerves are fucked as it is. This was supposed to be easy! Docker lied to me.
Anyway, the whole point of this is to have everything in Docker images and no dev env setup on my machine (aside from IDE).

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having then? Cookies belong to the domains that set them; there shouldn't be much of an issue using the HTTPS server cookie in the HTTP client. Do you get any errors reported in the browser console? What **exactly** isn't working? FYI, nothing to do with Docker given the React app runs in your browser

Comment: The cookie is set correctly - `.main-domain.localhost`. But the frontend refuses to accept this cookie, because the browser says that both backend and frontend need to have the same protocol for it to accept it (unfortunately I can't screenshot this because Chrome hides the tooltip as soon as I press Win+Shift+S). And that has everything to do with frontend needing to be HTTPS, which refuses to work seemingly because of Docker. All of this is described in my question.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error that indicates anything _"refuses to accept this cookie"_? Are you attempting to read the cookie client-side or do you just want it to represent the session, in which case you should never need to read it, just include it in requests via `credentials: "include"`

Comment: How many times do I have to repeat - THE BROWSER refuses to accept it! Check the added screenshot, Print Screen didn't hide the tooltip.

Comment: There's always subtleties in error messages which aren't conveyed by simple statements like _"it refuses to accept"_. Thanks to the screenshot I can now confidently say that you should change the server's cookie configuration to use `SameSite=None`. Then you'll be able to use different origins for client and server. You could have also simply copied the error message text if taking a screenshot was difficult

Comment: If it is for development you can set the samesite to None

Comment: That's great, but I don't want to use `SameSite=None`, I want to configure React to work in HTTPS, which should also fix this error! That is what's said in the title of this question! There is nothing wrong with wanting HTTPS in development!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your server is running over HTTPS and you're already using the `Secure` attribute, you can enable `SameSite=None` in your cookie settings to properly support cross-domain credentials.

Then you should be able to connect using any client host (CORS notwithstanding).

This might be convenient if you intend on using separate hosts in production since you wouldn't need to toggle `SameSite` based on environment.

---

Otherwise, it doesn't look like you're running the React app with `HTTPS=true`. If you added the `ENV` commands to your `Dockerfile` after initially running the app, you'll need to rebuild your image

```shell
docker compose build
```

Alternately, avoid things that might change regularly in your Docker build and simply set them at runtime

```yaml
environment:
  - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
  - HTTPS=true
  - SSL_CRT_FILE=/opt/project/ssl/cert.pem
  - SSL_KEY_FILE=/opt/project/ssl/key.pem
```

Then you should be able to open `https://localhost:3011` in your browser (or whatever mapped hostname you feel like using).

```
cra-node-1  | Starting the development server...
cra-node-1  |
cra-node-1  | Compiled successfully!
cra-node-1  |
cra-node-1  | You can now view cra in the browser.
cra-node-1  |
cra-node-1  |   Local:            https://localhost:3011
cra-node-1  |   On Your Network:  https://172.18.0.2:3011
cra-node-1  |
cra-node-1  | Note that the development build is not optimized.
cra-node-1  | To create a production build, use npm run build.
cra-node-1  |
cra-node-1  | webpack compiled successfully
```

Comment: Sigh... the damned `build`. I had already forgotten about it because often my containers hang up and refuse to be `down`ed (something to do with WSL it seems), so I just restarted Docker or my PC, deleted the container/image/volume, and did a fresh `up`. This should have worked for the environment variables as well, but I guess I managed to squeeze in a `down` + `up` in there for once, which obviously doesn't rebuild. I did manage to get HTTPS working in React, although backend died instead, but at least my question is answered. I don't think I will be changing these variables any more though.

Comment: @jurchiks Just in case you don't know about it, you can always run `docker compose up --build` to always check for build changes

Comment: Sure, but I don't ever run the docker commands, I have a Makefile with `build`/`up`/`down`, etc.